# C++ atomic list container

Tags: c++, list, stl, containers, atomic

I'm playing around with `std::atomic` but I think I didn't fully understand the concept. I'm wondering why there are no atomic Containers. So I played a little bit around. First I tried the following:

```
std::atomic<std::list<int> > atomicList;
```

But as already some other people pointed out that this doesn't work because the constructor is `noexcept`. So I created some kind of hack:

```
template<class T>
class MyList
{
public:
    //Make sure that no exception is thrown
    MyList() noexcept
        try: l()
    {}catch(...) {}

    void push_back(const T &t) { l.push_back(t); }

    void pop_front() { l.pop_front(); }

    size_t size() const { return l.size(); }

private:
    list<T> l;

};

atomic<MyList<int> > atomicList;
```

Now I worked with it but I discovered that it doesn't work properly and I get Segmentation fault errors.

Can somebody please explain why it is not possible to create an atomic list this way?

EDIT: If someone wants to see how my test program really looks for better understanding:

```
#include <list>
#include <thread>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class MyList
{

public:
    MyList() noexcept
        try: l()
    {}catch(...) {}

    void push_back(const T &t) { l.push_back(t); }

    void pop_front() { l.pop_front(); }

    size_t size() const { return l.size(); }

private:
    list<T> l;

};

atomic<MyList<int> > l;

void work()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        //Called operator()
        ((MyList<int>&)l).push_back(i);
        ((MyList<int>&)l).push_back(((MyList<int>&)l).size());
        ((MyList<int>&)l).pop_front();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    struct timeval time1;
    struct timeval time2;
    gettimeofday(&time1, 0);
    thread t1(work);
    thread t2(work);
    thread t3(work);
    thread t4(work);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    gettimeofday(&time2, 0);
    cout<<((time2.tv_sec-time1.tv_sec)+double(time2.tv_usec-time1.tv_usec)/1000000)<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first and most important problem: this can't possibly work. You need synchronization around the execution of the member functions, not around retrieving the list. `std::atomic` doesn't even begin to resemble what you need.

Regarding your attempted implementation, casting an `atomic<T>` to `T&` can't do anything reasonable.

And even if it were meaningful, such a cast would completely forget the atomicness of your object, and so anything you do with the references won't be atomic  operations.

Comment: OK I understand. So is it actually possible to *convert* an stl Container to be atomic? Or is it necessary to create it from scratch?

Comment: @Thomas: You could try to write a container adapter, but I think you would be much better off thinking in terms of "write it from scratch, but maybe use a standard container internally". Especially since the `Container` concept is actually *impossible* to make atomic, unless their `value_type` is some specialized object that cooperates with the container to behave atomically (e.g. how could `C[i]=x;` possibly be implemented as an atomic operation?).

Answer (score 1):

```
((MyList<int>&)l).push_back(i);
```

[`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) does not provide a conversion operator to a reference. Had you used a `static_cast`, it wouldn't even compile, but here the C-cast is directly reinterpreting the `std::atomic<MyList<int>>` as a `MyList<int>`, which has good reasons not to work.

You cannot directly modify what's in an `std::atomic`. You need to retrieve a copy of the data with `load()`, modify this copy, and then swap it back with `store()`.

Comment: So should it work it I did: `MyList<int> temp = l.load()` then modify `temp` and store it back using `l.store(temp)` Can you please add that to your answer?

Comment: And another Thing: So what is the `operator()` for if I can't use it directly?

Comment: @ThomasSparber yes, it would. But as Hurkyl points out, the only thing `std::atomic` provides is an atomic load/store operation. It doesn't synchronize what you actually do to the data, it only ensures that when you swap it out for new data everyone gets a complete object. The conversion operator converts to `T`, not `T&`, and is just syntactic sugar over a `load()`.